# compare .csv data using orange

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, orange, botnet

I have converted packet capture (.pcap) file of network traffic that has botnet behaviour into .csv file.

From the .csv, I had gain information about the botnet throughput.

My main question here is, how can I use orange as a machine learning algorithm to prove there is botnet activity in the .csv file

Thanks, I am a very newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. Orange is just a tool. Yes, it's a friendly tool, but you will need to know something about machine learning before you can use it. There are plenty of free MOOCs on these topics, so pick one that you like.